# What mixer should I use?

Tags: software-recommendation, audio-recording, podcast, mixer, usb

I plan on recording a podcast on Garageband. I have rode procaster mic. I will be using one mic and one phone input with irig to connect audio caller, I need one more input to connect ipad to play music during the recording. So basically three inputs is what i need so far, which USB mixer do you recommend that can record individual tracks in garageband for my voice/caller and music? Something not too expensive ofcourse.

Comment: Instead of recording the audio output of your music player, maybe you could get the music audio file(s) and then edit those into the podcast, directly in Garageband ? Thant way, you wouldn't need more inputs on the mixer.

Answer (score 0):

I have used Behringer mixers in the past and they have always done the job. Behringer makes a variety of mixers and plenty of them are priced below $100. Any of [these mixers](https://www.amazon.com/s/ref=nb_sb_noss_2?url=search-alias%3Daps&field-keywords=behringer%20mixer) should do the job. Just make sure you purchase the mixer with the appropriate number of inputs and any additional features you may want.

Answer (score 0):

Both Alesis and Behringer make mixers where you plug your iPad in and can do all the work on the iPad touchscreen, they normally have at least 2 inputs (some having 4) and all work with the core audio and Garageband apps enabling you to record and mix multi-channels